# How to create <div> with special form in CSS or Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am new to front end development and I have to create  with a special apparence.

I am french and I don't really know what am I looking for to create the shape I need.
So there is a part of the mock-up :

So I was wondering how to make the border of my div in diagonale?

I think about using canvas, or just simply put a div with a image-background corresponding. But what are the other options I have to do it? And in your opinion, what is the best?

[image: Shape Mock-Up]

Comment: Please show us What you have tried?

Comment: Chris Coyier used SVG for the shapes in his navigation: http://css-tricks.com/svg-tabs-using-svg-shape-template/

Comment: I haven't try anything yet, I want to be sure I am using an adapted tool! @CSSApprentice your link bring me to the same page! :/

Comment: BTW To do shapes with CSS, check out http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/ for examples to get you started.

Comment: @stephenhay Both can be a good solution, apparently exactly what I need. I will test the two options and give a solution for everyone in my situation! Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this perhaps?:

HTML:

```
<div id="header">LE BON REFLEXE</div>
```

CSS:

```
div#header
{
    display:inline-block;
    width:auto;
    height:20px;
    padding:5px 20px 5px 10px;
    background:none #3476A9;
    color:#fff;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-family:arial;
    position:relative;
    overflow:visible;     
}
div#header:after
{
    content:'';
    display:block;    
    width:20px;
    height:30px;
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    right:-5px;
    background:none #3476A9;
    -webkit-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -moz-transform: skew(-20deg);
    -o-transform: skew(-20deg);
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/b4TGG/3/

Answer (score 1):

You have a few option to create shapes.
The most known one is to draw borders with different colors.

Css3 offers today some transform possibilities,

pseudo-elements, shadows and borders mixed together can offer lots possibilities as well,

border-radius too.

position, display, float can be used to place element wherever you wish like any content.

Here something quiet similar to your screen : **[DEMO](http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/Fajpk)**

Basicly from :

```
<div class="shapes">
  <h1>Shapes ?</h1>
</div>
```

and some CSS

```
shapes {
  margin:0 4em;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
}
.shapes:before {
  content:'';
  width:4em;
  height:30em;
  float:left;
  background:gray;
  transform:rotate(10deg);
  transform-origin:top right;
  position:relative;
  z-index:1;
}
h1 {
  border-top:1em solid #2C3744;
  margin:0;
  color:white;
  background:#3476A9;
}
h1:after {
  content:'';
  padding:0.61em;
  background:white;
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  margin-left:1em;
  margin-right:-100%;
  transform:skew(-15deg);
}
```

*[and here plenty more ideas](http://codepen.io/collection/LbCzx/)*

Comment: I forgot to mention background gradients that are very usefull too :)